# Updating strongly typed Dataset from local Sql Compact database

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, sql-server-ce

I created with Visual Studio 2010 Express a Sql Compact Database (sdf-File), with several tables and relations. From this database I generated a strongly typed dataset.

Now I want to fill the dataset with the content from the database.
So I used following code to connect to the database and fill the dataset.

```
//My strongly typed dataset
localData = new LokalStorageDataSet();

//SqlCe-Connection
localConnection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TempStorage.sdf; Password='xyc';Persist Security Info=True");

localConnection.Open();
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM progstates", localConnection);
localDataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);

localDataAdapter.Fill(localData);
```

The problem is that no rows were added to my dataset, although in the database there are rows.
If I use a SqlCeReader to read the results of the SqlCeCommand, the reader return the rows:

```
SqlCeDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
          ...
        }
```

Can you give me the reason why my dataset don't get the rows from the table in the dataset?

EDIT: I saw that in my dataset a new datatable were created named 'Table' with the same columns like the one I requested (progstate) but also this datatable has a rowCount of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EDITED *****

Try This :-

//My strongly typed dataset
localData = new LokalStorageDataSet();

//SqlCe-Connection
localConnection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TempStorage.sdf; Password='xyc';Persist Security Info=True");


SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM progstates", localConnection);

localConnection.Open();

var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

localData.Load(dataReader,LoadOption.Upsert,localData.Tables[0]);

localConnection.Close();
```

Or You cant do this with DataAdapter like this :-

```
localDataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter();

SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM progstates", localConnection);

localDataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;

localConnection.Open();

localDataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
localDataAdapter.Fill(localData.Tables[0]);

localConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Hm this works, thanks! But why doesn't it work with a SqlCeDataAdapter? I would prefer it if I could use the Adapter. I also have to use it when I write the data from the dataset back to the database (with dataAdapter.Update(dataset);). Unfortunatly this doesn't works neither. :(

Comment: Hm can you describe the method to do this, please? I don't find a suitable method on the dataset class.

Comment: Using the Update method of the DataAdapter, is something else you will need to explore yourself, it not relevant to your issue in the post.